# ReturnedRect are inverted after upgrade

Tags: java, opencv, geometry

I'm working on a big project, and we need to upgrade OpenCV from 3.2 to 4.6 on our Java project.

Using the exact same image I've got inverted results:

Getting contours :

```
matOfPoint = contours.get(i);
MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(matOfPoint.toArray());
RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(contour2f);
```

I version 3.2 of OpenCV result of **rotatedRect** is:

```
{{485.0001220703125, 641.5073852539062} 793x23 * -0.5055378675460815}}
```

In version 4.6:

```
{{485.0000915527344, 641.5073852539062} 23x793 * 89.49445343017578}}
```

Why are the **width**, **height** and **angles** inverted?

I've got a bunch of calculations after this, and I would like to avoid changing them too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *reason* for the differing results would take some archaeology to find. OpenCV 3.2 is quite old. A lot of OpenCV's internals may have been improved since then. I don't think the docs specify the range of angles or relationship between width and height. It would have been acceptable for someone to change the implementation details.

Dismissing differences beginning in the third or fourth decimal, those two representations are ***equivalent*** though:

```
{{485.0001220703125, 641.5073852539062} 793x23 * -0.5055378675460815}}
{{485.0000915527344, 641.5073852539062} 23x793 * 89.49445343017578}}
```

`(-0.5055) % 90 = 89.4945`

90 degrees is a quarter turn. A quarter turn is equivalent to swapping width and height.

If you need them in some canonical form, swap size and adjust angle to be positive and less than 90 degrees.

Or better yet, because that can jitter for boxes with close to 0 degrees of angle: canonize the angle to be within -45 to +45 degrees. That makes sense to do if you expect mostly axis-aligned objects.

Pseudocode/Python:

```py
old_angle = np.linspace(-90, +90, 7)
temp = old_angle + 45
quarter_turns = temp // 90 # division and floor
new_angle = temp % 90 - 45

# array([-90., -60., -30.,   0.,  30.,  60.,  90.]) # old_angle
# array([ -1.,  -1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.]) # quarter_turns
# array([  0.,  30., -30.,   0.,  30., -30.,   0.]) # new_angle

...

if quarter_turns % 2 != 0: # single angle, not array
    height, width = width, height
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I know those 2 are "equivalent".
But as we do a lot of transformation depending on the angles, etc ... I kinda broke everything.

I just wanted to know why those are different after the upgrade.

Comment: perhaps someone tweaked the implementation in opencv. maybe it's just some numerical matter that happened to settle one way or another. impossible to know. an upgrade from v3.2 is long overdue though. you can expect a lot of internals to have changed since then. the results will be equivalent or better though. opencv contains some regression tests and accuracy tests. they would notice if anything were changing for the worse.

Comment: I agree. 
Thanks for your clear answer. I will tweak everything on our side then.